# On KENWOOD TS2000, the CW messages don't record even after the "recording wait" pops up in the display. But the sidetone works fine

Tags: transceiver, cw, kenwood

I'm working on a miniproject where i'm asked to demonstrate the recording of some signal.

I made a keyer connection using a earphone cable to my Kenwood. The Keyer works fine - the sidetone is audible but if I try to record it, nothing gets recorded as I mentioned above.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: I think it is unclear what you are trying to do. Do you want to record a signal that was received "over the air"? Do you want to record a CW message into the rig's memory? What functions / buttons / menu items are you using on the TS2000?

Comment: I want to record a CW signal that I am inputting into the device using a keyer that I connected using a earphone cable.
[function]+[channel3] starts the recording process - "rec wait" and "CP3" (as i am trying in channel 3) pops up but when I give keyer input, nothing is entered.

If I enable the bug key mode, even the [funcion] + [channel3] doesn't work ("rec wait" itself is not displayed)
If I just click the channel button, I am not able to enter any channel too to check if anything is recorded.

Frequency - 444.999 MHz
Split mode enabled
AUTO, ATT and NR1 is on.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the keyer doesn't actually generate any tone; instead, the radio is just generating the modulated signal as an RF output.  The result is that there is no "audio" to record because it doesn't exist until it hits the antenna.

Comment: Recording a CW message to one of the transceiver's CW memories is not about recording an audio tone but about recording the dot and dash impulses.

Comment: "If I enable the bug key mode, even the [funcion] + [channel3] doesn't work", please note that the manual specifies this behaviour; p. 43 in the manual: "When the Bug Key function is ON, CW Message Memory cannot be used".

Answer (score 1):

It appears that recording a CW message may only be possible with a paddle key (single oder dual lever) plugged into the PADDLE connector at the back. Using an external keyer for forming dots and dashes and plugging it into the KEY connector will not record to the CW message memory. (tested that with a Kenwood TS590)

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer! So when exactly should I use the keyer?

Comment: Since the TS2000 has an internal keyer, it is not necessary to use an external keyer, unless the external one provides needed functions that are not covered by the transceiver's internal keyer.